# Laravel 4: Submitting <option> Value To Controller

Tags: laravel-4

I have a form which is generated in a controller before being passed to the view:

```
public function displayUsers(){
    $html = "";

    //get all users
    $users = $this->entityManager->getRepository('User')->findBy(array(), array('last_name'=>'ASC')); 
    if($users){
        $html .= '<h3>Permissions By User</h3>';
        $html .= '<select class="form-control" id="permissions-username">';
        foreach($users as $user){
            $html .= '<option value="'.$user->getId().'">'.$user->getLastName().', '.$user->getFirstName().'</option>';
        }
        $html .= '</select>';
    }
    return View::make('admin')->with('output', $html);  
}
```

Then in the 'admin' view, I have the following to display the form:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route'=>'permissions.edit', 'method' => 'GET')) }}
        <div class="form-group">
            @if($output)
                {{ $output }}
            @endif
        </div>
        {{ Form::submit('Edit User', ['class'=>'btn btn-warning btn-sm', 'name' => 'edit_user', 'title'=>'Edit User']) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

When I submit this form to the controller, the value of the selected option is not carried over. The output of the permissions.edit function ends up as:

```
{"edit_user":"Edit User"}
```

With a generated URL of:

```
*(BASE)*/permissions/%7Bpermissions%7D/edit?edit_user=Edit+User
```

If I create a form on the view using blade templating, this problem is resolved. However, I do not want to have all the logic of the form on my view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your `select` has no name, which is right now as geven below:

```
<select class="form-control" id="permissions-username">
```

Assign a `name` to it, for example, something like this:

```
<select name="permissions_username" class="form-control" id="permissions-username">
```

Every form element must have a name otherwise you can't access them on server side. So, now you are able to access that element on the server (in your script) using something like this (In case of `Laravel`):

```
$permissions_username = Input::get('permissions_username');
```

Otherwise (Using Vanilla `PHP`) you may use:

```
$permissions_username = $_GET['permissions_username'];
```

Because you've used `GET` method in the form. So, whatever you use, you need to assign a name to your form's element, it's necessary (Even with or without `Laravel`).